# SQL count column that includes __, no repeats?

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm trying to count the number of 'invoices' that include a line item less than 20, using two tables, but without repeating invoice count (sorry it's difficult to explain)

This is what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.invoice_id) 
FROM invoices a, invoice_line_items b 
WHERE b.line_item_amount < 20;
```

and this result:

```
+---------------------+
| COUNT(a.invoice_id) |
+---------------------+
|                1710 |          |
+---------------------+
```

but when I just do `SELECT`, I noticed that there was the same invoice multiple times (as it contained more than one line item with the condition).  How do I fix this? I know I could use distinct but I don't know where to place it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ilt.invoice_id)
FROM invoice_line_items ilt
WHERE ilt.line_item_amount < 20;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases.